# Threads blocked once DBCP connection pool becomes empty

Tags: java, oracle, connection-pooling, spring-jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

I have a Spring JdbcTemplate object initialized with a DBCP connection pool. Every now and then the applications becomes unresponsive because about a hundered threads are now hung because they are unable to fetch a connection from the DBCP pool, and they stay like that for ever. Only restarting the applictaion fixes the issue.

```
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <46251453> (a org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool$Latch)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1118)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:630)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:727)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:737)
at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForObject(JdbcTemplate.java:805)
```

A look at the heap dump revealed that the the pool has no objects i.e.,
(PoolingDataSource)DataSource.(GenericPoolObject)_pool.(CursorableLinkedList)_pool.(int)_size==0

```
this     - value: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource #2
 -> dataSource     - class: org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource, value: org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource #1
  -> _pool     - class: org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource, value: org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool #1
   -> _pool     - class: org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool, value: org.apache.commons.pool.impl.CursorableLinkedList #1
    -> _size     - class: org.apache.commons.pool.impl.CursorableLinkedList, value: int 0
```

It seems the pooled connections were evicted after being idle for the specified threshold (10 minutes) and then new connections are not being created.

- All these threads are trying to do different operations on different tables so table locking causing this is unlikely.
- I have verified the (Oracle) Database state to see if there are any active sessions waiting for a commit: there are none.
- Also other instances of the appliaction using the same DB are not impacted at the time.
- I have also ruled out any network issues. The data base is reachable and I am able to connect using our Sql client

Any clues?

---

### Update

I enabled DBCP abandoned connection logging with a timeout of about 20 minutes. There are a number of abandoned connections. However, since the connection creation and release is happening through Spring JDBCTemplate, I can not do any connection handling explicitly. I am still trying to solve this puzzle.

Comment: I suggest you are leaking connections.

Comment: @EJP I have verified that there are no explicit invocations to the getConnection on the dataSource. All operations are happeing through the JDBCTemplate which should cleanly handle connection closing. Even then, shouldn't any leaked connections be automatically evicted after they remain idle for the specified threshold duration? Also, If there were any leaked connections, I'd expect the value of the _pool variable to be non-zero. It seems that there is not an absence of available connections albeit an absence of absolultely any connections at all.

Comment: @EJP I enabled DBCP abandoned connection logging and, voila, there are a bunch of abandoned connections. Not sure what I can do though, as the connection creation and release is happening through Spring JDBCTemplate outside the reach of my code.

Comment: any update on this? encountering the same issue

Comment: @yolob 21 It seems the connection pooling library was not behaving reliably under highly concurrent access. I put a cache between the application code and the jdbctemplate api to reduce number of db hits, and the problem went away. I came across some posts somewhere that dbcp was buggy and  a pooling alternative like c3p0 should be preferred over dbcp. Need to try that, though